# Loop through object and replace values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an object which at some points is four levels deep, however I want a function that will cope should more levels be introduced. I'm trying to write a function that will replaced elements such that `<span class="ajax-parent1-parent2-parent3-value"></span>` will be replaced with `parent1.parent2.parent3.value`.

The issue is that the depth is variable, so I could have something like `<span class="ajax-parent1-value"></span>` to be replaced with `parent1.value`.

Finally, it's not always the text to be replaced. Optionally, `data-attr` can specify an attribute to be used instead (through `element.attr(<data-attr>, <value>)`).

Currently, I'm iterating manually, however it isn't very clean so I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. This also doesn't work for greater than two levels deep.

```
function render(data) {
  $.each(data, function(parent, value) {
    $.each(value, function(element, value) {
      $el = $('.ajax-' + parent + '-' + element);
      $.each($el, function(key, el) {
        if ($(el).data('attr')) {
          $(el).attr($(el).data('attr'), value);
        } else {
          $(el).text(value);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Example object:

```
{
  "profile": {
    "username": "johnd",
    "bio": "Some example data about John",
    "website": "http://john.com",
    "profile_picture": "http://john.com/me.jpg",
    "full_name": "John Doe",
    "counts": {
      "media": 13,
      "followed_by": 26,
      "follows": 49
    },
    "id": "16"
  },
  "dashboard": {
    "script": {
      "tags": ["media"],
      "stats": {
        "liked": 0,
        "lastrun": "never",
        "duration": 0
      },
      "status": {
        "code": 0,
        "slug": "disabled",
        "human": "Disabled",
        "message": "Not running."
      }
    },
    "account": {
      "plan": "free",
      "created": 1419261005373,
      "updated": 1419261005373
    }
  },
  "serverInformation": {
    "serverName": "Johns API",
    "apiVersion": "0.0.1",
    "requestDuration": 22,
    "currentTime": 1419262805646
  },
  "requesterInformation": {
    "id": "redacted",
    "fingerprint": "redacted",
    "remoteIP": "redacted",
    "receivedParams": {
      "action": "getDashboard",
      "apiVersion": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `class="ajax-parent1.value"` it's a bad practise to use `dot` in class name

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef The HTML doesn't matter, it all follows the pattern of `<span class="ajax-<value in object>"` where a new level is indicated with a `-`.

Comment: @demo Oops, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: If possible , can post an example `data` object ? Thanks

Comment: Does "This also doesn't work for greater than two levels deep." refer to  the selector `$el = $('.ajax-' + parent + '-' + element);` ?

Comment: Yes. Well, for the entire of the function I've got so far.

Comment: Still not entirely certain about requirement ? Tried utilizing Attribute Contains Prefix Selector [name|="value"] http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/ or Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"] http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/ ? Or `filter` http://api.jquery.com/filter to select `$el` based on `data` properties , values ?

Comment: Split the task by two parts - Part 1- ensure each node which has to be visited gets visited. Part 2- ensure the appropriate action is taken for each visited node. You don't need to know the depth as you can use a recursive function. Please come up with a self containing sample demoing the most complex case.

Comment: Would it not be easier to extract JSON out of your HTML (using jQuery), manipulate with JSON and then produce the HTML of it? I wouldn't go for a generic solution as you'll likely end with a monstrous framework in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I wrote:

```
function iterate(obj, stack) {
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
        iterate(obj[property], stack + '-' + property);
      } else {
        $group = $('.ajax' + stack + '-' + property);
        $.each($group, function(key, element) {
          if ($(element).data('attr')) {
            $(element).attr($(element).data('attr'), obj[property]);
          } else {
            $(element).text(obj[property]);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start from the HTML, so you only access the properties you actually want to render?

That way you can keep it quite simple (also note that this removes the need to nest HTML spans in the same order/depth as the data object, you can just place any HTML node anywhere. Just make sure you don't  use class/node names more then once.

```
function parseData(data) {
    var $container = $('.ajax');

    $container.find("[class^='ajax-']").each(function(i, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        if ($el.children().length === 0)
        {
            var nodes = $el.attr('class').split('-');
            nodes.shift();

            var node = data;
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                node = node[nodes[i]];

                if (typeof(node) == "undefined") {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ($el.data('attr'))
            {
                $el.attr($el.data('attr'), node);
            }
            else
            {
                $el.text(node);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Fiddle here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ckcduLhn/5/